# not sure if tensorflow is running on GPU or CPU custom keras training loop or if its a problem with the training loop code

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

the python script is using 20% of my CPU and only 0.3% of my GPU.
I am still very new to Keras and TensorFlow so it is not at all unlikely that I am doing something wrong which is causing this excessive slowness. program should be running for 15000 training episodes with each episode consisting of 400 steps. No images or fancy stuff is used, the state is just a simple list of 3 elements. At the current rate it would take about 100 hours to run all 15000 episodes. I would really like to be sure that TensorFlow is using my GPU to run if someone can help me with that.
additionally if anyone has any comments on my custom training loop i would greatly appreciate that too.

---Custom Training loop---

```
for episode in range(1,num_training_episodes+1):
    done = False
    episode_reward = 0
    state = env.reset_environment(sat)
    for step in range(num_steps):

        action = agent.select_action(state, policy_net)
        new_state, episode_reward, done = env.step(sat, action)
        memory.push(Experience(state.copy(), action, new_state.copy(), episode_reward))
        state = new_state

        if memory.can_provide_sample(batch_size):

            states, actions, new_states, rewards = memory.sample(batch_size)

            next_q_values = target_net.predict(new_states)
            target_q_values = rewards +gamma*tf.reduce_max(next_q_values, axis = 1)

            masks = tf.one_hot(actions, num_actions)

            with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                q_values = policy_net(np.array([states]))[0]

                q_action = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(q_values, masks), axis = 1)

                loss = loss_func(target_q_values, q_action)

            grads = tape.gradient(loss, policy_net.trainable_variables)
            optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, policy_net.trainable_variables))

        if (done == True) or (step == num_steps-1):
            reward_list.append(episode_reward)
            break

    if (episode % target_update) == 0:
        for layer_policy,layer_target in zip(policy_net.layers,target_net.layers):
            layer_target.set_weights(layer_policy.get_weights())

    if (episode % print_every) == 0:
        print("Episode:", episode-print_every, "to:", episode, "Number of correct stops:", env.correct_stop_counter, "Mean rewards:", np.mean(reward_list[episode-print_every:episode]))
```

---console output---

```
2020-09-30 21:47:06.446861: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-09-30 21:47:08.497370: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2020-09-30 21:47:08.527588: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1060 computeCapability: 6.1
coreClock: 1.6705GHz coreCount: 10 deviceMemorySize: 6.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 178.99GiB/s
2020-09-30 21:47:08.528543: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-09-30 21:47:08.534707: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-09-30 21:47:08.540359: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2020-09-30 21:47:08.542732: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2020-09-30 21:47:08.548640: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-09-30 21:47:08.552110: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2020-09-30 21:47:08.565173: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-09-30 21:47:08.565677: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1858] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
Num GPUs Available:  1
2020-09-30 21:47:08.576341: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2020-09-30 21:47:08.588414: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x18df008a400 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-09-30 21:47:08.589123: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2020-09-30 21:47:08.590160: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1060 computeCapability: 6.1
coreClock: 1.6705GHz coreCount: 10 deviceMemorySize: 6.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 178.99GiB/s
2020-09-30 21:47:08.590965: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-09-30 21:47:08.591530: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-09-30 21:47:08.591898: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2020-09-30 21:47:08.592195: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2020-09-30 21:47:08.592657: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-09-30 21:47:08.593051: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2020-09-30 21:47:08.593582: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-09-30 21:47:08.594160: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1858] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-09-30 21:47:09.346067: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1257] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-09-30 21:47:09.346584: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1263]      0 
2020-09-30 21:47:09.346967: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1276] 0:   N 
2020-09-30 21:47:09.347409: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1402] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 4826 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1060, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2020-09-30 21:47:09.352153: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x18da6c97700 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-09-30 21:47:09.352903: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): GeForce GTX 1060, Compute Capability 6.1
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense (Dense)                (None, 24)                96        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 48)                1200      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 24)                1176      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 5)                 125       
=================================================================
Total params: 2,597
Trainable params: 2,597
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 24)                96        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 48)                1200      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_6 (Dense)              (None, 24)                1176      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_7 (Dense)              (None, 5)                 125       
=================================================================
Total params: 2,597
Trainable params: 2,597
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
2020-09-30 21:47:09.444165: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
```

Comment: You can turn off GPU visibility by setting an environmental variable, either from outside of your script or inside. Inside: `os.envrion['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = -1`. Try that and see if there's a performance difference. Also, `nvidia-smi` will show you if tensorflow is using your GPU

Comment: Hey so I ran nvidia-smi via my command line and it seems like my GPU is not being used by tensorflow, any tips on how i can get it to use my GPU. im already running this line at the start of my script                                                          
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(physical_devices))
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)

Comment: The GPU is being used, but the problem is that your model is very small so it does not benefit from GPU acceleration, since there is a cost to move data from CPU to GPU.

Comment: hmm okay, so any idea why its running so extremely slowly?

Comment: I just told you, the model is too simple/small.

Comment: so the model is too small that its running slowly? sorry that just seems a bit counterintuitive

Comment: Yes, because speedups come from running CPU and GPU in parallel, and the GPU having a large computational capability, but you are using only 0.3% of that GPU, so the bottleneck becomes the CPU to GPU (and back to CPU) transfer and this slows down the whole pipeline. It might be faster to train the whole model on CPU (have you tried this?).

Comment: You could also increase the batch size since this will increase GPU utilization, but I do not think it will be significant.

Comment: Thanks for all the help already, I just tested running the program on only my CPU and it still runs very slowly maybe even slightly slower at about 30 seconds an episode